# tumblr embeds creating blank space

Tags: html, css, tumblr

remaking this after like a month because ive been lazy. anyway, whenever i post embed links or videos or whatever, it looks fine as an actual post but glitches out and creates large gaps of empty space on the post.

ive gone through the code but im not great at coding so i cant really figure out what would fix the issue or whats causing it or whatever, all i know is that it has something to do with tumblr changing how embeds work

link: https://mycomaboyfriend.tumblr.com/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.